# Export to Excel - intermediate file formats?

Tags: xml, excel, csv, delphi, delphi-6

I am trying to export very large amount of data (300.000 rows * 100 columns) to Excel (from Delphi application) and OLE approach (combined solution from DevExpress DX, CX suites and out own code) gives error messages *Not enough storage is available to complete this operation*, *Error creating variant array*. There is no good and ready third party components for native export and there for I have idea to use intermediate file: **I can export data in some intermediate file and then open this file in Excelt. But what format is the most suitable for such action?**:ddd

- CSV is the most simple one, but can Excel recover the column format from the CSV data - it is very important for us, that currency data are exported as numbers and calculations can be done on them, that date data are exported as dates. CSV has no this type information.
- XML seems to be promising, because typing and formatting can be added to the data but what is the format of XML that Excel requires, is this format described anywhere?
- DB file seems to be promising to, but it is quite old and I am not sure whether there is no limits on the amount of data.

I am looking solution for Delphi 6.

Comment: With [XLSReadWriteII](http://www.axolot.com/xls.htm) you can read/write into XLS format directly without Excel.

Comment: Maybe SQLLite? But I am not sure if it's ok for such a big amounts of rows..

Comment: @LURD thank for mentioning. I haven't worked with excel stuff for years now. But nice to know that there is such a library!

Comment: If you are looking for a solution for Delphi 6 (as I assume from your comment to the first answer), you should state so.

Comment: That's a lot of data. I'd be looking for 64 bit processes. You are making life hard by insisting on ancient  compiler and 32 bkt

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use AdoDataSet. You can directly write to Excel files via Adodataset. You only have to use the correct connectionstring: [connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/). These are all MS components and should have no problems with large datasets.